# How to close popup window after clicking on submit button without page reload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a Script to open one popup with form(for comparing the input field value with one fixed code) on page load & after clicking on the submit button need to close popup without page reload. Here is my code.
"Html form code"

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return checkCode(this);">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

"Script Code"
"popup script"

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        overlay.show();
        overlay.appendTo(document.body);
        $('.popup').show();
        $('.close').click(function () {
            $('.popup').hide();
            overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

"comparing function code"

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function checkCode(theForm) {
        if (theForm.name.value != 'SS-2018') {
            alert('Code not matched!');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please check this & help me to get it working correctly. Everything is working correctly I just want on click submit page don't reload simply close the popup window & keep on the same page.
Thanks & Regards
Cue

Comment: if you don't want the button to submit the form, change it's type to type="button" instead of submit.

Comment: i did the same then its not comparing the form values. you please try to with this may it works.may i missed something. Thanks

Comment: Why are you returning false at the end of $('.close').click handler?

Comment: sir not working like this.

Comment: Submitting a form will always cause a "page reload".  If you don't want a "page reload" then you'll need to use AJAX to POST the form.  Before making the ajax request you call your `checkCode` code.

Comment: ok sir can you please provide the ajax code for this?? because i am not expert in ajax. Thanks

Comment: Sure, it's the code that's been provided by @samanime

Comment: sir have you try with this code bcz here its not working. i think you should try this code & run the web page & then you see what happens. else if possible please try it in Jquery-fiddle & provide me the working code link. Thanks

Comment: If you have `onsubmit="return checkCode(this);"` on the form and `function checkCode() { return false; }` then your form will *not* submit.  If it is still submitting, then, simply, you have something else on your page/form that you have not told us about, so we can't help you any further.

Comment: _"i did the same then its not comparing the form values"_ - because now the button does not submit the form any more, so the onsubmit handler on the form element isn't triggered either. So replace it with onclick on the button itself, and done ...

Comment: Have a read of [mcve] with emphasis on the *complete and verifiable* example.  Your code is not complete and does not reproduce the issue, in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the HTML that you have there is inside of your popup or overlay. It's a bit hard to tell.

If you want to submit the form without reloading or changing the page, you'll have to use some form of AJAX. Since it looks like you are using `jQuery`, you can use their [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function.

To get the data of the form itself, you can use their [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to scoop the data up into a POJO (plain old JavaScript object).

You would do this on whatever makes sense to call submit. You could probably do it instead of your `return true` in your `checkCode()` function (and always `return false`).

It'd be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function checkCode(theForm) {
        if (theForm.name.value != 'SS-2018') {
            alert('Code not matched!');
        } else {
            $.ajax('http://example.com/post/location', { method: 'post', data: $(theForm).serialize() })
              .then(response => { /* do something with response */ })
              .catch(err => { /* handle error */ });
        }

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No sir its not working its again refreshing the page . i want to close the popup window without page reload. Please you try to do with this by changing the code & get it working. Thanks